# how to implement sorted list by newest with Firestore query

Tags: javascript, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have already tried:

```js
this.afs.collection('profiles', ref => {
   return  ref.where('createdAt', '>', 0).orderBy('createdAt', 'desc');
  });
```

but it not working.

Comment: See my answer here that might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46745076/how-to-orderbyvalue-onsnapshot-using-firestore

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get?

Cloud Firestore uses indexes for every query. You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing).

For your simple query it cloud look something like this (if using firebase [cli](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools)), else you can also create the index by using the link in the console (from the error).

`"indexes": [
    {
      "collectionId": "profiles",
      "fields": [
        { "fieldPath": "createdAt", "mode": "DESCENDING"}
      ]
    }
]`