# How to orderByValue onSnapshot using Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

In `componentWillMount` I am registering an onSnapshot function which updates the state.

```
componentWillMount () {
    todoRef.onSnapshot((doc) => {
      let todos = []
      doc.forEach(doc => {todos.push(doc.data())})
      this.setState({
        todos
      })
    })
  }
```

However, the way that firebase/firestore works is that it just pushes up random keys, so when I get the data back it's not in the correct order.

I know there is a `.orderByValue()` function but I've tried implementing it and can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My ref was `const todoRef = db.collection("todos");`

So once you've got the reference to your collection, you can then do the sort query.

```
todoRef.orderBy('createdAt').onSnapshot((docSnapShot) => {
  let todos = []
  docSnapShot.forEach(doc => {todos.push(doc.data())})
  this.setState({
    todos
  })
})
```

Answer (score 5):

```
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection('todo_collection')
      .orderBy('dateTime')
      .onSnapshot((snapshots) => {
        setTodos(snapshots.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
      });
  }, []);
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

For Firebase +9.0.0, you need to create a query and provide the orderBy as an argument:

we import the functions we need

```
import {collection, orderBy,query, onSnapshot};
```

let's create the collection reference

```
const collRef = collection(db,"todos");
```

let's create the query now : the first argument is a reference to our collection, the second is orderBy(pass a field name: string)

```
const q = query (collRef, orderBy("createdAt"));
```

Now we can pass it to the onsnapshot fuction.

```
onSnphot(q,(snapshot)=>{
//things to do with the snapshot
 let todos = []
  snapshot.forEach(doc => {todos.push(doc.data())})
  this.setState({
    todos
  })
})
```